# SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error while using c2dm

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm, service-not-available

I am trying to get C2DM to work, I'm following the ChrometoPhone example [here](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/)
When my emulator tries to register to C2DM, I get `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`. I have checked that the emulator has a gmail account set up and the same account is being passed as `senderId` from `DeviceRegistrar.java` in the example code. I am also sure that my emulator can access the Internet and I have all permissions (to access the Internet, wake lock etc.). What else can be wrong here?

I'm not sure if I did a good job of explaining the problem. Please let me know if I need to explain something else.

Here is `C2DMBaseReceiver.java`

```
package com.apps.terrapin;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Base class for C2D message receiver. Includes constants for the
 * strings used in the protocol.
 */
public abstract class C2DMBaseReceiver extends IntentService {
    private static final String C2DM_RETRY = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RETRY";

    public static final String REGISTRATION_CALLBACK_INTENT = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION";
    private static final String C2DM_INTENT = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE";

    // Logging tag
    private static final String TAG = "C2DM";

    // Extras in the registration callback intents.
    public static final String EXTRA_UNREGISTERED = "unregistered";

    public static final String EXTRA_ERROR = "error";

    public static final String EXTRA_REGISTRATION_ID = "registration_id";

    public static final String ERR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE = "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE";
    public static final String ERR_ACCOUNT_MISSING = "ACCOUNT_MISSING";
    public static final String ERR_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED = "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED";
    public static final String ERR_TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS = "TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS";
    public static final String ERR_INVALID_PARAMETERS = "INVALID_PARAMETERS";
    public static final String ERR_INVALID_SENDER = "INVALID_SENDER";
    public static final String ERR_PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR = "PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR";

    // wakelock
    private static final String WAKELOCK_KEY = "C2DM_LIB";

    private static PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
    private final String senderId;

    /**
     * The C2DMReceiver class must create a no-arg constructor and pass the 
     * sender id to be used for registration.
     */
    public C2DMBaseReceiver(String senderId) {
        // senderId is used as base name for threads, etc.
        super(senderId);
        this.senderId = senderId;
    }

    /**
     * Called when a cloud message has been received.
     */
    protected abstract void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent);

    /**
     * Called on registration error. Override to provide better
     * error messages.
     *  
     * This is called in the context of a Service - no dialog or UI.
     */
    public abstract void onError(Context context, String errorId);

    /**
     * Called when a registration token has been received.
     */
    public void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) throws IOException {
        // registrationId will also be saved
    }

    /**
     * Called when the device has been unregistered.
     */
    public void onUnregistered(Context context) {
    }


    @Override
    public final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            if (intent.getAction().equals(REGISTRATION_CALLBACK_INTENT)) {
                handleRegistration(context, intent);
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(C2DM_INTENT)) {
                onMessage(context, intent);
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(C2DM_RETRY)) {
                C2DMessaging.register(context, senderId);
            }
        } finally {
            //  Release the power lock, so phone can get back to sleep.
            // The lock is reference counted by default, so multiple 
            // messages are ok.

            // If the onMessage() needs to spawn a thread or do something else,
            // it should use it's own lock.
            mWakeLock.release();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Called from the broadcast receiver. 
     * Will process the received intent, call handleMessage(), registered(), etc.
     * in background threads, with a wake lock, while keeping the service 
     * alive. 
     */
    static void runIntentInService(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (mWakeLock == null) {
            // This is called from BroadcastReceiver, there is no init.
            PowerManager pm = 
                (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 
                    WAKELOCK_KEY);
        }
        mWakeLock.acquire();

        // Use a naming convention, similar with how permissions and intents are 
        // used. Alternatives are introspection or an ugly use of statics. 
        String receiver = context.getPackageName() + ".C2DMReceiver";
        intent.setClassName(context, receiver);

        context.startService(intent);

    }


    private void handleRegistration(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String registrationId = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_REGISTRATION_ID);
        String error = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ERROR);
        String removed = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_UNREGISTERED);

        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "dmControl: registrationId = " + registrationId +
                ", error = " + error + ", removed = " + removed);
        }

        if (removed != null) {
            // Remember we are unregistered
            C2DMessaging.clearRegistrationId(context);
            onUnregistered(context);
            return;
        } else if (error != null) {
            // we are not registered, can try again
            C2DMessaging.clearRegistrationId(context);
            // Registration failed
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration error " + error);
            onError(context, error);
            if ("SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE".equals(error)) {
                long backoffTimeMs = C2DMessaging.getBackoff(context);

                Log.d(TAG, "Scheduling registration retry, backoff = " + backoffTimeMs);
                Intent retryIntent = new Intent(C2DM_RETRY);
                PendingIntent retryPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 
                        0 /*requestCode*/, retryIntent, 0 /*flags*/);

                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                        backoffTimeMs, retryPIntent);

                // Next retry should wait longer.
                backoffTimeMs *= 2;
                C2DMessaging.setBackoff(context, backoffTimeMs);
            } 
        } else {
            try {
                onRegistered(context, registrationId);
                C2DMessaging.setRegistrationId(context, registrationId);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration error " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

C2DMBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package com.apps.terrapin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Helper class to handle BroadcastReciver behavior.
 * - can only run for a limited amount of time - it must start a real service 
 * for longer activity
 * - must get the power lock, must make sure it's released when all done.
 * 
 */
public class C2DMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // To keep things in one place.
        C2DMBaseReceiver.runIntentInService(context, intent);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null /* data */, null /* extra */);

        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Broadcast receiver got REGISTRATION");
            Log.e("TAG", "ID: " + intent.getExtras().getString("registration_id"));

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Broadcast receiver got message");
         }
    }
}
```

C2DMessaging.java

```
package com.apps.terrapin;

/*
 * Copyright 2010 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

/**
 * Utilities for device registration.
 *
 * Will keep track of the registration token in a private preference.
 */
public class C2DMessaging {
    public static final String EXTRA_SENDER = "sender";
    public static final String EXTRA_APPLICATION_PENDING_INTENT = "app";
    public static final String REQUEST_UNREGISTRATION_INTENT = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER";
    public static final String REQUEST_REGISTRATION_INTENT = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER";
    public static final String LAST_REGISTRATION_CHANGE = "last_registration_change";
    public static final String BACKOFF = "backoff";
    public static final String GSF_PACKAGE = "com.google.android.gsf";


    // package
    static final String PREFERENCE = "com.google.android.c2dm";

    private static final long DEFAULT_BACKOFF = 30000;

    /**
     * Initiate c2d messaging registration for the current application
     */
    public static void register(Context context, String senderId) {
        Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
        //registrationIntent.setPackage(GSF_PACKAGE);
        registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
        registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", senderId);
        context.startService(registrationIntent);
    }

    /**
     * Unregister the application. New messages will be blocked by server.
     */
    public static void unregister(Context context) {
        Intent regIntent = new Intent(REQUEST_UNREGISTRATION_INTENT);
        regIntent.setPackage(GSF_PACKAGE);
        regIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_APPLICATION_PENDING_INTENT, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, new Intent(), 0));
        context.startService(regIntent);
    }

    /**
     * Return the current registration id.
     *
     * If result is empty, the registration has failed.
     *
     * @return registration id, or empty string if the registration is not complete.
     */
    public static String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
                PREFERENCE,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString("dm_registration", "");
        return registrationId;
    }

    public static long getLastRegistrationChange(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
                PREFERENCE,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getLong(LAST_REGISTRATION_CHANGE, 0);
    }

    static long getBackoff(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
                PREFERENCE,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getLong(BACKOFF, DEFAULT_BACKOFF);
    }

    static void setBackoff(Context context, long backoff) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
                PREFERENCE,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong(BACKOFF, backoff);
        editor.commit();

    }

    // package
    static void clearRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
                PREFERENCE,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("dm_registration", "");
        editor.putLong(LAST_REGISTRATION_CHANGE, System.currentTimeMillis());
        editor.commit();

    }

    // package
    static void setRegistrationId(Context context, String registrationId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
                PREFERENCE,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("dm_registration", registrationId);
        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

C2DMReceiver.java

```
package com.apps.terrapin;

/*
 * Copyright 2010 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class C2DMReceiver extends C2DMBaseReceiver {
    public C2DMReceiver() {
        super(DeviceRegistrar.SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRegistered(Context context, String registration) {
        DeviceRegistrar.registerWithServer(context, registration);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnregistered(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = Prefs.get(context);
        String deviceRegistrationID = prefs.getString("deviceRegistrationID",
                null);
        DeviceRegistrar.unregisterWithServer(context, deviceRegistrationID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error ocurred in onError");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String msg = extras.getString("message");

        Log.e("TAG", "Got a message from cloud: " + msg);
    }
}
```

DeviceRegistrar.java

```
package com.apps.terrapin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class DeviceRegistrar {
    static final String SENDER_ID = "sender@gmail.com";

    public static void registerWithServer(final Context context, final String deviceRegistrationID) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

        String url = "http://" + "192.168.1.11" + "/message.php?";
        url += "device=" + deviceRegistrationID;

        try {
            request.setURI(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            Log.d("@@@@@ Server response @@@@@", response.toString());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void unregisterWithServer(final Context context, final String deviceRegistrationID) {

    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    package="com.apps.terrapin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->    
    <permission android:name="com.apps.terrapin.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.apps.terrapin.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Permissions for internet access and account access -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- App must have this permission to use the library -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/earth"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".TerraPin" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TakePictureActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <service android:name=".C2DMReceiver" />

        <!-- Only google service can send data messages for the app. If permission is not set -
             any other app can generate it --> 
        <receiver android:name="com.apps.terrapin.C2DMBroadcastReceiver"
                  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <!-- Receive the actual message -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.apps.terrapin" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Receive the registration id -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.apps.terrapin" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

</manifest>
```

The error returned is `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`

In my main activity, I am doing this:

```
C2DMessaging.register(this, DeviceRegistrar.SENDER_ID);
        String regId = C2DMessaging.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId != null && !"".equals(regId)) {
            DeviceRegistrar.registerWithServer(this, regId);
        } else {
            C2DMessaging.register(this, DeviceRegistrar.SENDER_ID);
        }
```

Comment: Have you registered the gmail account with the C2DM signup service?...http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html

Comment: yes, did that. I got the confirmation email saying the account is whitelisted.

Comment: OK, so posting some code might be helpful. Also, what is the response code you are getting?

Comment: Added code. The response says SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, then the backoff kicks in and when it retires, it gets the same response.

Comment: r u using 2.2? try using a different emulator

Comment: I tried this on 2.3.3 and 4.0. Got the same error

Comment: Abhishek, how long did you have to wait for the confirmation email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Android Virtual Device Manager edit your Android Virtual Device (AVD) and set the target "Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 8" instead of "Android 2.2 - API Level 8". After doing that run your emulator and in the settings set your google account (put the whitelisted email).

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Worked for me too. I'm not sure why this did not work on 2.3.3